# CompilerException java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using for in clojure

Tags: clojure

I typed this in repl(or something else using `for`):

```
(defn foo [m f]
  (into {} (for [[k v] m] [k (f v)])))
```

repl throws:
CompilerException java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/core$for$to_groups__5217, compiling:(*cider-repl localhost*:4:12)

I do not know the reason why?
The project is using Clojure 1.8.0. I checked the doc of `for`, it shows that `for` has been defined since version 1.0.

Comment: is this error persistent over a restart of the repl?

Comment: NO.... Thanks very much. So maybe the honeysql problem I asked yesterday is just the same.

Comment: I guess it is the environment problem. The code is correct for me.

Comment: Yes. After restarting repl, it works well now.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by myself:

This was because that the original .jar file being replaced or deleted, so the Java Runtime cannot find the origin class definition.

To solve this:

1. recover the original .jar file.

or:

2. restart the Java process with the new .jar file.